# Facebook Canvas POST ASP.net

Tags: .net, facebook, canvas

Facebook is requiring all canvas apps to support HTTP POST in the iframe instead of GET.  However, when I enable the feature, ASP.net complains that

`The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/' is not allowed`

For some reason Facebook requires a path that does not have an extension in it (for example it requires `mydomain.com/random/` instead of `mydomain.com/mypage.aspx`).

How can I enable POST for aspx pages and the root (default) page in my web.config page so I can develop my app locally?  I belive the configuration on IIS is more straightforward.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did u find out something new?

Comment: All I've found is that it works fine on IIS but not locally.  My solution below is a quick hack to fix it locally, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workable solution by "rewriting" the requests to my root path in the Global.asax file.  Works for development server, but will probably have to be removed in production:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string p = Request.Path;
  if (p.Equals("/myapp/")) {
    var query = "?" + Request.QueryString.ToString();
    if (query.Equals("?")) {
      query = "";
    }
    Context.RewritePath("/myapp/Default.aspx" + query);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fascinating. I didn't believe it until I tried it. I was able to get rid of the exception when running this in VStudio's web server by adding `<add verb="*" path="/" type="System.Web.UI.Page"/>` to the `<httpHandlers>` section. The trick is, it didn't actually display the default page, or run the Page_Load event. I replaced `System.Web.UI.Page` with the namespace and type of my default page, and this time the Page_Load event ran, but the markup in the .aspx file seems to have been ignored. A call to Response.Write() in the Page_Load event did result in output to the browser.

So, maybe that's useful on its own, or maybe it points you in the right direction.

I also don't really know what side effects this might have, though, so proceed with caution.

Edit: The type you want can be found in the machine.config--`System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory`

Comment: Yes--you can use that type in the web.config modification I showed earlier. The disclaimer about side effects stands :)

Answer (score 0):

don't think you can... Instead of localhost, you actually have to push your app out to a server on the web that the FB servers can see, then your app should work.